# Excel Chart Label Formatting Issue

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel is not formatting my chart data labels correctly. I'm trying to display some markers on a chart, corresponding to dates; however, after a certain point, the labels lose their formatting and are reverted to standard decimals numbers, probably calendar days since an epoch.

[image: Excel Chart]

Notice that to position the markers where I want them vertically, I had to make the dates the Category Name and the values the same number.

Also note that the formatting only applies to labels before a certain date. For example, if the second marker you see above had a Category of May 9, the label would show 43594. How can I get these labels to format correctly, no matter the date?

Comment: Check the source text box.. It should be formatted as d-mmm (date).

Comment: Each of the three source text boxes is formatted the same (a date plus a number of days)

Comment: "a date plus a number of days" is the formula.. I mean when you r-click > format cell > Number > custom > "d-mmm" ..